# R- Word co-occurrence frequency within paragraph

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

The dataset contains text data of 26 news articles.
I would like to count word co-occurrence frequency within each paragraph, but it seems that my codes below are doing within a document (a whole article). 
Can you designate the level (sentence, paragraph...) for calculating co-occurrence frequency with fcm()? 
Or is there any other package to do so?

```
library(quanteda)
library(readtext)
library(tm)

##corpus
tf_pb <- readtext("PB_articles.csv",text_field = "text")
tf2_pb  <- gsub(pattern = "\\b(rifle|rifles|weapon|weapons)\\b", replace = "gun", x = tf_pb)
corpus_pb <- corpus(tf2_pb)

summary(corpus_pb)

##Tokenization&Cleaning
tkn_pb <- tokens(corpus_pb,
                 remove_url = TRUE,
                 remove_numbers = TRUE,
                 remove_punct = TRUE,
                 remove_symbols = TRUE,
                 remove_separators = TRUE)

##removeing stopwords & stemming
stm_pb <- tokens_wordstem(tkn_pb)
stw_pb <- tokens_remove(stm_pb, pattern = stopwords('en'))


##multi-word expression
multiword <- c("social media", "house of worship")
comp_toks <- tokens_compound(stw_pb, pattern = phrase(multiword))
comp_toks

##keyword_list
kw_pb <- lapply(comp_toks, function(x){ x[which(grepl("\\b(synagogu|jewish|rabbi|jew|anti-semit|pittsburgh|congre|communiti|member|hous|worship|weapon|rifle|gun|shooting|assault|attack|hate|hatr|twitter|social_media|morn|gab|white|post|gun|funer|victim|prayer|rabinowitz|suspect|religi|account|nation|door|friend|charge|shiva|wax|speech|home|leader)\\b", x))]})
head(kw_pb)

##tokenにする
tkn2_pb <- as.tokens(kw_pb)

##remove words
tkn3_pb <- tokens_select(tkn2_pb,c("next-door","consumer-friend","ar-15-gun-mass-shootings.html",
                                 "hate-fuel","hate-fil","prayer.ImageOutsid","door.Th",
                                 "we-need-to-stop-the-hate-rabbi-tells-elected-leaders.html","speech.CreditCredit",
                                 "hate-rel","shooting.Credit","shooting.Polic","pittsburgh-shooting-synagogue.html",
                                 "media.Ar","shooting.Speedi","speech.Gab","shooting.Thi","shooting.On","gun-control",
                                 "gun.ImageAR-15","shooting.In","gun-safeti","pic.twitter.com","post-World","home.But","worship.Th"),
                         selection = "remove", padding = FALSE)

##co-occurrence frequency
fcm_pb <- fcm(tkn3_pb,
             count = "frequency")
```

Comment: As you didn't provide the data, I can't give a definite answer (and that's why I don't post this as an answer). But the first thing you should try is to reshape the corpus. `corpus_pb_param <- corpus_reshape(corpus_pb, to = 'paragraphs')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is first to reshape the corpus into paragraphs, so that the new "documents" are then paragraphs from the original documents, and then compute the fcm with a "document" co-occurrence context.

Here's an example you can adapt, using the first three documents from the built-in inaugural address corpus.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.0.1

data_corpus_inauguralpara <-
  corpus_reshape(data_corpus_inaugural[1:3], to = "paragraphs")
summary(data_corpus_inauguralpara)
## Corpus consisting of 23 documents, showing 23 documents:
## 
##               Text Types Tokens Sentences Year  President FirstName      Party
##  1789-Washington.1     8     11         1 1789 Washington    George       none
##  1789-Washington.2   184    341         5 1789 Washington    George       none
##  1789-Washington.3   192    328         6 1789 Washington    George       none
##  1789-Washington.4   214    391         5 1789 Washington    George       none
##  1789-Washington.5   120    182         2 1789 Washington    George       none
##  1789-Washington.6   102    164         4 1789 Washington    George       none
##  1789-Washington.7    88    120         1 1789 Washington    George       none
##  1793-Washington.1    47     64         2 1793 Washington    George       none
##  1793-Washington.2    61     83         2 1793 Washington    George       none
##       1797-Adams.1   114    180         2 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##       1797-Adams.2    88    137         3 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##       1797-Adams.3    63    101         1 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##       1797-Adams.4    60     82         3 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##       1797-Adams.5   145    277         6 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##       1797-Adams.6    62    108         2 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##       1797-Adams.7    16     17         1 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##       1797-Adams.8   158    303         8 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##       1797-Adams.9    97    184         4 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##      1797-Adams.10    80    128         1 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##      1797-Adams.11    74    119         3 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##      1797-Adams.12   329    808         1 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##      1797-Adams.13    51     75         1 1797      Adams      John Federalist
##      1797-Adams.14    41     58         1 1797      Adams      John Federalist
```

You can see here how the documents are now paragraphs.  Now, tokenize it and add your own manipulations to the tokens (you had several in your question), and then compute the fcm.

```r
# add your own additional manipulation of tokens here: compounding, etc
toks <- data_corpus_inauguralpara %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(stopwords("en"))

# this creates the fcm within paragraph
fcmat <- fcm(toks, context = "document")
fcmat
## Feature co-occurrence matrix of: 1,093 by 1,093 features.
##                  features
## features          Fellow-Citizens Senate House Representatives Among
##   Fellow-Citizens               0      1     1               1     0
##   Senate                        0      0     1               1     0
##   House                         0      0     0               2     0
##   Representatives               0      0     0               0     0
##   Among                         0      0     0               0     0
##   vicissitudes                  0      0     0               0     0
##   incident                      0      0     0               0     0
##   life                          0      0     0               0     0
##   event                         0      0     0               0     0
##   filled                        0      0     0               0     0
##                  features
## features          vicissitudes incident life event filled
##   Fellow-Citizens            0        0    0     0      0
##   Senate                     0        0    0     0      0
##   House                      0        0    0     0      0
##   Representatives            0        0    0     0      0
##   Among                      1        1    1     1      1
##   vicissitudes               0        1    1     1      1
##   incident                   0        0    1     1      1
##   life                       0        0    1     1      1
##   event                      0        0    0     0      1
##   filled                     0        0    0     0      0
## [ reached max_feat ... 1,083 more features, reached max_nfeat ... 1,083 more features ]
```